# How to create 'child' questions in Django forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to know how to create 'child' questions using Django forms. Thats is, questions which are only visible depending on the answer provided in a preceding question.

I'm fairly sure I'm not using the correct terminology with the term 'child' questions but I am sure someone will figure out what I mean

In the below example, when the user selects "United States of America" The option to select which state they are from should become visible. This would be standard on my website forms.

Is there a standard functionality available to do this?

**Country List**

```
   COUNTRY = (   
        ("", "----------"), 
        (AFGHANISTAN, 'Afghanistan'),
        (ALBANIA, 'Albania'),
        ....
        (UNITED STATES OF AMERICA, 'United States of America'),
        ....
        (ZAMBIA, 'Zambia'),
        (ZIMBABWE, 'Zimbabwe'),

        COUNTRY = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=COUNTRY, initial="", label='What Country are you from?')
```

**State list**

```
STATE = (
        ("", "----------"), 
        (ALABAMA, 'Alabama'),
        (ALASKA, 'Alaska'),
        (ARIZONA, 'Arizona'),
        ....
        ....
        (WYOMING, 'Wyoming'),
        (DISTRICT_OF_COLUMBIA, 'District of Columbia'),
        (PUERTO_RICO, 'Puerto Rico'),
        (GUAM, 'Guam'),
        (AMERICAN_SAMOA, 'American Samoa'),
        (US_VIRGIN_ISLANDS, 'US Virgin Islands'),
        (NORTHERN_MARIANO_ISLANDS, 'Northern Mariana Islands'),
            )

    state = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=STATE, initial="", label='What State are you from?')
```

Comment: Django does not do this out of the box. There's a third party package, `django-smart-selects`, that I've seen some people use for at least some parts of this - it definitely tries to handle cases where the options for one field depend on the value of another, but I'm not sure it handles cases where you don't even wan to show the select input except for some values. I haven't worked with it myself, I just see it mentioned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use javascript to show/hide the "child" selector, and then when you process your form, only save a state value if the country value is USA.