# multi combo box in django

Tags: django, forms, combobox, models

I have a model called Bar:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I want the user to be able to choose a bar through a combox box of first choosing a country, than a city (in that country), than a bar(in that city).

I tried doing it with django forms, but no success. What is the best way to do it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look on ChoiceField at [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield):

> "(Default widget: Select)"

ChoiceField is rendered as select box in HTML. It should work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Django Smart Selects

- [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-smart-selects/1.0.9)
- [Blog post about implementation here](http://nickbewley.com/development/chained-select-boxes-in-django/)
- You can also fork it on GitHub I believe

I was recommended this in the past when I asked a similar question about [How to create 'child' questions in Django forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918951/how-to-create-child-questions-in-django-forms) I never got a chance to play around with it but it seems very close to what you are looking for.

I was also never sure what to call this type of functionality but it seems like "Chained Select Boxes" which  got from the above post is the best I've heard so far.